# How to update a ModelForm's initial values dynamically?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-generic-views

I'm trying to create a dynamic form which pre-populates the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial) attribute of a certain field (`title`) when another field (`checkin_type`) is selected from a drop-down menu.

I'm using Django's generic [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview), and the way I'd like to go about it is by overriding the view's `post()` method such that if it receives an AJAX request (which is triggered by a jQuery `.change()` in the aforementioned drop-down menu and contains the `id` of the selection option), it updates the `initial` property of the form's `title`.

Here is the view I've tried so far (in `views.py`):

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import CheckIn, CheckInType


class CheckInCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = CheckIn
    fields = '__all__'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            checkin_type = CheckInType.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
            form = self.get_form()
            form['title'].initial = checkin_type.title
            self.object = CheckIn.objects.create(checkin_type=checkin_type)
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
        else:
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is how the AJAX request is made in the form's template, called `templates/dashboard/checkin_form.html` in accordance with Django's naming convention (`dashboard` is the name of the app):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        $(".auto-submit").change(function() {
            $.post({
                url: "{% url 'checkin-create' %}",
                data: {id: $(".auto-submit option:selected").val()}
            })
        });
    });
</script>


<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="{% if field.name == 'checkin_type' %}auto-submit{% endif %}">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

Here are the corresponding models (in `models.py`):

```
from django.db import models


class CheckInType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CheckIn(models.Model):
    checkin_type = models.ForeignKey(CheckInType, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    # Scheduling
    requested_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    completed_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The problem is that when I select an option from the drop-down menu for `checkin_type`, I see no change in the form:

[image]

I would have expected the `Title` field to become pre-populated with '1-week check-in' in this example. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Issue is in js code, you are calling change event on div, whereas you should call this on select Id or class. Second is on post ajax call there's no success / done method to set title.

Comment: I'm actually trying to set the `title` in the form's `post` method, not in the Javascript code. Also, I'm quite sure the `id` was passed in as I checked it by dropping into the debugger (it has a value of `1` in this example). The problem is getting the form to re-render in the desired fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you change
`form['title'].initial = checkin_type.title`
to
`form.cleaned_data['title'] = checkin_type.title`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, and in any case it wouldn't achieve the same thing: [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial) specifies a value to use when rendering the field, but the field is not actually set to that value (yet).